# Library containing enum for all PostgreSQL error codes

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

I want to throw custom exceptions depending on what SQLException is caught. Is there a maven repository with a library containing an enum of all of PostgreSQL's error codes?

E.g.

```
try {
    doSomethingThatThrowsAnSqlException();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if (e.getSQLState().equals(PostgreSQLError.UNIQUE_VIOLATION.getCode())) {
        throw new CustomException("custom message");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Comment: why dont you create a custom class with enums from here? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/errcodes-appendix.html

Comment: @Apostolos because it would be a waste of work and prone to human error... anyways it looks like e.getErrorCode() didn't return exactly what I expected...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a readily available repository for this, but you can find the error codes and their meanings in the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html). From there, it shouldn't be to much work to create your own enum.

Comment: Creating my own enum is exactly what I am trying to avoid here.

Comment: yes i understand but having e.g. 50 entries ready in a list and making them enums is a 5-10 minute work.

Comment: @Apostolos True, I might end up doing that. Just adding new entries as I need them. But it seems like one of those things that would be readily available and maintained somewhere already :)